# Is this the example of Lexical analysis error?

Tags: compiler-construction

Consider the below statement.

char a=`a;

What kind of error is it, lexical or syntax in case of compiler design?

Answer (score 3):

It is neither.

Who says this construct is not valid?

It depends solely on your definitions.

For example, you may have defined that ` signs may only occur in pairs, like " for describing string literals. Then it would be a lexical error.

OTOH, ` could be some predefined infix operator, like *. Then this would be a syntax error, as the left hand side of the expression is missing.

Or ` could be an unary operator on integers, then it would be a type error, as a is obviously a char.

Comment: One can make reasonable assumptions about OP's question.

Comment: @IraBaxter Or one can answer it like it was asked. It is very well possible that OP thinks that there is some pre-defined, fixed, immovable border between lexical and syntax errrors, no matter what language. Also, you could as well assume Java. Or Haskell, where a definition like `char a = a` would at least make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Its "just" a syntax error; syntax tells you what is legal to write and this is not.

People will talk about a special kind of syntax error, and say that there is a malformed token, or lexeme.  But that's a detail relevant only *inside* the compiler.

If *you* wrote this code, it is *your* mistake, not the compiler's.

Comment: Where do you know that it is not legal?

Comment: Check the language reference manual.  (I assume that OP meant "C" as the language since he appear to be writing something that is mostly valid in C and C is widely used.).

Comment: @IraBaxter In C this would be a lexical error though - not a syntax error (which you agree with in your second sentence, so I'm not sure why you claim otherwise in your first sentence).

Comment: Technically its a syntax error: you're not allowed to write it, according to the language syntax.

Comment: It's a syntax error if you use that term to include lexical errors. But when the question is "Is this is a syntax error or lexical error?", that interpretation of "syntax error" is clearly not intended.

Comment: "But that's a detail relevant only inside the compiler." Which, I assume, is why this question was tagged "compiler construction". The whole question was "is the a syntax or lexing error?". "That's relevant only in the compiler" is not a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

If a backtick or a backtick followed by letters is a valid token in your language, this is a syntax error (unless "backtick followed by identifier" is actually a syntactically valid expression in your language, of course).

If your language does not have a backtick or backtick followed by letters token, it's a lexical error.

If your language (somewhat surprisingly/counter-intuitively) uses backticks for character literals (using the form backtick, character, backtick), it's still a lexical error because the character literal is unclosed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lexical error.

---

Regular expression for character could be 
'((\.)|[^\'])'

---

This will accept any char like 'a', 'z', '\t', '\n'.

If your lexer does not find starting or ending single quote it will flag a lexical error.
This would have been syntax error if a or = or 'a' or ; was/were missing from the expression above.